# How to reload self ViewController with few changes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a customVC nib view in which tableview items are displaying from url .Now on clicking a button here I need to reload the same viewcontroller with some  other request sent to api . My data is  again reloading  and the response is coming but only  tableview data is not changing based on the response. The old data is still loading...

```
class CustomAddOnVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var myAddOnUrl = "http://\(platform).eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=\(apiID)&app_key=\(apikey)&request=addon&aid=\(PASSADDON!)"

 @IBAction func ContinueBtn(sender: AnyObject){
    if checkCount == 0{
        print("Please Select one Item")
     }else{
          if addOnNext != 0
          {
            //here i am changing my request  for url

            PASSADDON = String(addOnNext!)
            print(PASSADDON)

            let customVC = CustomAddOnVC()
            customVC.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
            presentViewController(customVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


            dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


            }
        }
```

my screen shots

[image]

Comment: Instead of presenting a new instance of `CustomAddOnVC` on top of itself, why not make the API request and then call `reloadData` on the table view?

Comment: In Api you can see only one request PASSADDON is changing .. and i need to display the same viewcontroler but only contents are different...@PauloFierro

Comment: I am adding my screen shots, my page should be like  that way@PauloFierro that why i have uses ".modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext"  property..